# making repetitive code generic

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Would it be possible to wrap repetitive code like this:

```
IList<Bla1> Bla1s = (from a in Containers
       where a.Right.GetType().Name.Equals("Bla1")
select
(
  (Bla1) a.Right
)).Distinct().ToList<Bla1>();
```

into a generic construct (method?). There are many Blas (Bla1, Bla2 ...). I guess Bla would represent T but I have not much experience with generics for such situations. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to test for the type and not just type name, then you can do:

```
IList<T> items = Containers.Select(c => c.Right).OfType<T>().Distinct().ToList();
```

Thus, your generic method could look like this:

```
IList<T> GenericMethod<T>()
{
    return Containers.Select(c => c.Right).OfType<T>().Distinct().ToList();
}
```

---

As hvd mentioned in the comments, the code above would also return any `Right` element that is of a type derived from `T`. If your intention is to filter for type `T` only, use this instead:

```
IList<T> GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<Container> containers)
{
    return containers.Select(c => c.Right)
        .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T)).Cast<T>()
        .Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Note: this means that a class derived from `T` will also be included. If that's not desirable, it's possible to use something like `.Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(T)).Cast<T>()`.

Comment: @hvd I have the feeling the OP wants to make an `is T` test, but you're right, that's not equivalent to the code in the question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The last GenericMethod works fine. please add Containers to the signature though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If the string you use is always exactly equal to the class name, then yes.

```
IList<T> Bla1s = (from a in Containers
       where a.Right.GetType().Name.Equals(typeof(T).Name)
select
(
  (T) a.Right
)).Distinct().ToList<T>();
```

Or drop the string entirely:

```
IList<T> Bla1s = (from a in Containers
       where a.Right.GetType().Equals(typeof(T))
select
(
  (T) a.Right
)).Distinct().ToList<T>();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried something similar the challenge currently lies with making this a static method ... I get some namespace error although I have imported System.Collections.Generic.

Comment: @csetzkorn making it static is another issue entirely. I would imagine `Containers` is a non-static member of some class, and hence a static function couldn't get there. You'll have to add more code or post a different question to get a more specific answer on that.